# protractor - sendKeys md-contact-chips not working

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

I am trying to set value using sendKeys in protractor in md-contact-chips.

I tried   element(by.model('skills')).sendKeys('Java'); but its not working. can anyone help me in protractor. Thanks

```
  <div>
 <md-content>
 <md-contact-chips  md-input-id="skillId"  ng- 
  required="skills.length<1" ng-model="skills" md- 
  contacts="querySearch($query)" md-contact-name="skill" md-require- 
 match="true" md-min-length="1" md-highlight-flags="i" filter- 
selected="true" placeholder="Enter a skill" secondary- 
 placeholder="Enter a 
skill </md-contact-chips></md-content> </div>
```

Comment: Hello, you are not new to this community but seems you have to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and correct your question.

Comment: Since i'm doing an comment, obviously question has been posted.

Comment: Check element is inside iframe?

Comment: It is in the form of popup..  $scope.openDemandForm = function() {

            $mdDialog.show({
            controller: "demandFormController",
            templateUrl: '/static/tdp/poc/demandForm/demandForm.tmpl.html',
            parent: angular.element(document.body),
            clickOutsideToClose:false,
            })
        };

Answer (score 0):

Try the below option

```
ele = element(by.css('md-content > md-contact-chips[md-input-id="skillId"]'));
```

**OR**

```
ele = element(by.css('md-content > md-contact-chips'));


it('Add New Demand', async function() { 
var el = element(by.css('md-content > md-contact-chips')); 
await el.sendKeys('Java'); }
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: var el = element(by.css('md-content > md-contact-chips'));
   el.sendKeys('Java'); I tried both the options. Both didnt work.

Comment: share the error you get along with complete html and your test code to give better visiblity on the error

Comment: No error .. just the value is not set.. it('Add New Demand', function() {
var el = element(by.css('md-content > md-contact-chips'));
el.sendKeys('Java');
} .

Comment: is the locator highlighting  the element in browser console?

Comment: try wit `async/await` in your test. Refer updated answer

Comment: Still it didnt work.. no error.. just the value does not get populated

Comment: is the locator highlighting the element in browser console?